# Applying a way to implement hyperparameter tuning with Keras Functional API

Tags: keras, deep-learning, neural-network, hyperparameters

I am working on a regression where in currently I have managed to define the architecture of my neural network which takes multiple inputs using the Keras functional API. However I haven't been able to tune the hyperparameters adequatelyusing either GridSearchCV  or hyperas as neither support the Keras Functional API.

1. I've tried to tune both of the branches separately but this does not make any true sense.

### Model Code:

```
def build_model(input1, input2):
    
    """
    Creates the a multi-channel ANN, capable of accepting multiple inputs.

    :param: none
    :return: the model of the ANN with a single output given
    """
    
    input1 = np.expand_dims(input1,1)

    # Define Input Layers for ANN
    input1 = Input(shape = (input1.shape[1],), name = "Input1")
    input2 = Input(shape = (input2.shape[1],), name = "Input2")

    # First Branch of ANN (Temperature)
    x = BatchNormalization()(input1)  
    x = Dense(units = 5, activation='relu', kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(0.001))(x)

    # Second Branch of ANN (Embeddings)
    y = BatchNormalization()(input2)  
    y = Dense(units = 64, activation = "relu", kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(0.001))(y)

    # Merge the input models into a single large vector
    concatenated = Concatenate()([x, y])
    
    #Apply Final Output Layer
    #outputs = BatchNormalization()(concatenated)  
    outputs = Dropout(0.08)(concatenated)
    outputs = Dense(1, name = "output")(outputs)

    # Create an Interpretation Model (Accepts the inputs from previous branches and has single output)
    model = Model(inputs = [input1, input2], outputs = outputs)
    
    # Compile the Model
    #model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer = Adam(lr = 0.001), metrics = ['mse'])
    model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer=AdaBound(lr=0.001, final_lr=0.1), metrics = ['mse'])

    # Summarize the Model Summary
    model.summary()
    
    return model
```

### Model Architecture

[image]

Comment: https://github.com/cerlymarco/keras-hypetune

Answer (score 1):

X and Y are arrays of X =[X0,x1,x2, ....] inputs trains and Y = [y0,y1,y2,...] outputs

def create_model(hp):

```
inputs=[]
concats=[]

# How many inputs different
for input in X:
    inp = Input(shape=input.shape[1])
    inputs.append(inp)

    # Hidden Layers start here
    minimum=input.shape[1]
    maximum=round(float(input.shape[1]) * 1.5)
    # How deeper you want 
    for i in range(hp.Int('num_layers', 2, 3)): #The minimum is 2, the max is 3.
        x = Dense(units=hp.Int('units_'+str(i)+'_'+str(minimum), min_value=minimum, max_value=maximum, step=2))(inp)
        x = BatchNormalization()(x)
        x = Activation(tf.keras.activations.swish)(x)
        x = Dropout(0.2)(x)

    concats.append(x)

concat = tf.keras.layers.Concatenate()(concats)

outputs = Dense(Y.shape[1])(concat)
outputs = Activation("sigmoid")(outputs)

model = Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=outputs)

model.compile(
    optimizer=tfa.optimizers.RectifiedAdam(learning_rate=1e-3),
    loss=BinaryCrossentropy(label_smoothing=1e-2),
    metrics='acc',
)

return model
```